# How to fix push/pulls in Mercurial HG (Potential problem with DNS)?

Tags: version-control, debian, mercurial, virtualbox

Today i have an issue. I cant do push/pulls in my Debian(on VM VirtualBox) using Mercurial HG.
What I have:

- Corporate VPN
- Oracle VM Virtual Box with launched Debian-based system
- Mercurial repository in my Debian-based system

The problem is: when I try to do a push, I get a bunch of errors `Name or service not known`. To solve it I tried to edit `hgrc` file by replacing this:
`[paths]`
`default = http://SERVER_NAME_STRING`
by this:
`[paths]`
`default = http://SERVER_IP_ADRES`
And it works! But I have to do it manually for each of hundreds `hgrc` files in my workspace tree. Can I fix this problem without editing of all of this files? (no matter manually or BASH scripts etc)

Comment: Have you done anything in the VM to setup a  proxy server address?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs No, I dont

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide an exact answer for debian; but I have a very similar setup with the guest OS being Windows. Windows has a setting to autoconfigure its proxy based on a corporate .pac script which is downloaded. I have a feeling you need to find the equivalent.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs thanks for your help! I post solution below, your way of thinking help me, but the easiest way was to edit `/etc/hosts/` :)

Comment: etc/hosts sounds like a nice simple approach! glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
There is 2 options:

1. Ask your system administrator for IP address of yours corporate DNS server and edit your DNS settings, by this IP
2. (**The easiest one**) Open `/etc/hosts` file and add new string of settings, by format `IP_ADDRESS`  `DOMAIN`

---

*After this action you will be able to ping your SVC server by domain.*